# In what IDE / compiler can I develop C++ code that will be deployed on FreeBSD server.

Tags: c++, linux, ide, freebsd

MY code will be deployed on FreeBSD. Would I be able to code using VS2010 in Win7? can this be done on Linux using gcc? or do I need to have freebsd installed on my laptop.

I plan on buying a new ultrabook and not sure FreeBSD will support the drivers or wireless. What the best practice here? VMs?

Thanks mods.

Comment: It depends of the kind of code (kernel drivers are different from textual processing). I would use Linux with `gcc` at first. The real issue is what *libraries* are you using...

Answer (score 1):

You can just write code in Visual Studio, however you will not be able to compile and run it in Windows, unless you are only using standard libraries.

To compile and test your code you need a FreeBSD somewhere.

I have never used FreeBSD on a laptop, so I can't say if dualbooting it with Windows is a good idea.

The best thing would be if you had access to a test server with the same configuration as your production server (i.e. same FreeBSD version, same packages, etc.). Then you could write code in VS, check it into a repository, SSH to the server, update a local copy of the source there and build.

If that is not an option, I recommend setting up a virtual environment. Download [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org), obtain FreeBSD and install it on the VM. Set up [port forwarding](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward) for SSH and then the process is pretty much the same as with a separate server. You may have to make some additional tweaks depending on the nature of the work you'll be doing.

Comment: Maybe my best is to use FreeBSD VM, and code directly on FreeBSD. This way I dont have to worry about drivers, and can use native libraries.  I was kinda hoping to try an alternative to Windows/VS, is there anything that can compete on *nix? Windows Manager + IDE. ty

Comment: There is no IDE like Visual Studio for FreeBSD. Most people would recommend you to get emacs or vim and use those for development. While those are great editors (I personally use vim), I doubt that you will find them good if you are used to VS. First, they are quite different, second, they require quite a bit of configuration to get something that is similar to VS's capabilities. That being said, you may want to try using vim or emacs eventually. For now, you can try Code::Blocks, which is also a nice IDE but doesn't quite compare to VS.

Comment: Installation instructions for codeblocks: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_Code::Blocks_from_source_on_FreeBSD

Comment: I used to code vi on *nix year ago. Never was an emacs guy. I as hoping to run native PC-BSD, and still be as productive as VS. I plan on doing lots of Aspect Oriented stuff and Code generation. Its a shame to be stuck on windows just because of VS.

Comment: For example... is there any IDE on *nix that will create stubs of pure virtual functions when I derive a class from an abstract base? After coding C# on VS for 5 years, not sure where to go with C++. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a setup I have used in cases where I am not using any OS specific library.

1. On your Windows 7 machine develop your application as usual without using MFC/ATL etc. If you are linking to external libraries/APIs you will have to use one which is portable across Windows and Linux (e.g. Boost libraries). Do not use pre-compiled headers (stdfax.h) or any other option which is Windows specific.
2. Get VirtualBox and install your favorite OS (FreeBSD in this case) and your favorite tool chain (gcc clang)
3. Share the disk/folder you are developing your app in the Windows file system so that it is visible in VirtualBox. In Ubuntu they end up in the /media/sf_Folder.
4. Compile in FreeBSD in VirtualBox. You will need to have an alternative make system setup in parallel in addition to the stuff Visual Studio creates. Make sure you do not have any conflicts in the way the directories used by the build system (to store object files etc.) between FreeBSD and Windows. You can try out this http://code.google.com/p/make-it-so/ to convert your VS solutions to gcc makefiles.

This way you can continue to use your favorite IDE and also rebuild on your target *ix OS on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

gcc + gvim + ( ( ctags with [omnicppcomplete](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CFoQFjAA&url=http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520&ei=wWnhT6DdG-iV0QXv8qWkAw&usg=AFQjCNE8YjH5nTSTfJvV79-y0Ww_0r0dtA) ) or ( [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) with [clang_complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302) ) and STL + Boost.